# creating keys for a dictionary from a list containing the keys

Tags: python, list, dictionary, python-2.7

I'm trying to build a matrix that holds several values in several levels.
I'm trying to generate a dictionary build up like this:

```
{'routername':{'channel':{'01':<value>,'02':<value>}}}
```

The number of keys on the highest level may vary.

The script is generating a list of available routers and another list of available channels.
I wrote a rather cumbersome function that test for a key and if it is not already there, it adds the key to the dictionary.

So, I was wondering if there isn't an easy way to create a dictionary with empty values for the keys in list 'routers'

```
def AddToChart(passed_seq):
    try:
        if str(passed_seq[0]) in chart_dict:
            if str(passed_seq[1]) in chart_dict[passed_seq[0]]:
                if str(passed_seq[2]) in chart_dict[passed_seq[0]][passed_seq[1]]:
                    if str(passed_seq[3]) in chart_dict[passed_seq[0]][passed_seq[1]][passed_seq[2]]:
                        chart_dict[passed_seq[0]][passed_seq[1]][passed_seq[2]][passed_seq[3]].update(err_sub_dict)

                    else:    
                        chart_dict[passed_seq[0]][passed_seq[1]][passed_seq[2]].update({passed_seq[3]:{}})
                        chart_dict[passed_seq[0]][passed_seq[1]][passed_seq[2]][passed_seq[3]].update(err_sub_dict)
                else:
                    chart_dict[passed_seq[0]][passed_seq[1]].update({passed_seq[2]:{passed_seq[3]:{}}})
                    chart_dict[passed_seq[0]][passed_seq[1]][passed_seq[2]][passed_seq[3]].update(err_sub_dict)
            else:
                chart_dict[passed_seq[0]].update({passed_seq[1]:{passed_seq[2]:{passed_seq[3]:{}}}})
                chart_dict[passed_seq[0]][passed_seq[1]][passed_seq[2]][passed_seq[3]].update(err_sub_dict)
        else:     
            chart_dict.update({passed_seq[0]:{passed_seq[1]:{passed_seq[2]:{passed_seq[3]:{}}}}})
            chart_dict[passed_seq[0]][passed_seq[1]][passed_seq[2]][passed_seq[3]].update(err_sub_dict)
    except ValueError:
        print "AddToChart: ",err_sub_dict,sys.exc_info()[1][0]   
    except:
        print sys.exc_info()
        print "AddToChart: variable not defined: "    + str(passed_seq)
```

Comment: What language is this? Please tag the language!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using a nested `collections.defaultdict` for `chart_dict`. It lets you provide a factory function to set up new values, so any key you request will always work. It's a little tricky to get such a deeply nested structure set up, but I think the following will do the right thing for your four-level structure (I'm assuming your `<value>` items are also dictionaries, as it seems your current code expects):

```
chart_dict = defaultdict(lambda:defaultdict(lambda:defaultdict(dict)))
```

With that in place, you should then be able to do the following without worrying about whether any of the keys previously referenced anything in the dictionary:

```
a, b, c = passed_seq
chart_dict[a][b][c].update(err_sub_dict)
```

I'd suggest doing something like the variable unpacking above too, though you should probably use better names than `a`, `b`, and `c`. Good variable names can turn something incomprehensible into something easy to grasp.

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```py
dict.setdefault()
```

See [docs](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault).

Example:

```py
d = {}
d = d.setdefault("k","eggs")

>> d["k"]
eggs

d2 = {"k":1}
d2 = d2.setdefault("k","spam")
>> d2["k"]
1
```